# RIA DomainService Query with parameters LightSwitch

Tags: ria, domainservices, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am trying to use RIA services in LightSwitch but I get an error when the query in the DomainService has a parameter because the query is not imported into LightSwitch.

All the other queries are fine.

The error I get when attaching the data source in the Wizard window is

> The parameter 'ID' in query 'AllRecordsbyId' is not a nullable type.
>   This query will not be imported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make the parameter nullable:

```
public IQueryable<CategoryTree> GetAllCategoryTree(int? AllRecordsbyId)
{
}
```

Comment: sure this answers the question.  However, why must all parameters be nullable?